# adding '+' to all the numbers as a prefix (numbers are stored in a csv file) using a python script

Tags: python, file-io

**goal**

All the numbers in the csv file that I exported from hotmail are stored as `91123456789` whereas to complete a call i need to dial `+91123456789`. These contacts will be converted to a batch of vcf files and exported to my phone. I want to add the + to all my contacts at the beginning.

**approach**

write a python script that can do this for an indefinite number of contacts.

**pre-conditions**

none of the numbers in the csv file will have a + in them.

**problem**

(a) there is a posibility that the number itself may have a `91` in it like: `+919658912365`. This makes the adding a plus very difficult.

explanation:I am adding this as a problem, as if the 91 is there only at the beginning of a number then we can add it simple by checking two consecutive digits and if they match `91` then we can add + else we don't need to add `+` and we can move on to the next pair of digits.

(b) the fields are seprated by comma's. I want to add the `+` as a prefix only in front of the field which has the header `mobile` and not in any other field where a set of digits `91` may appear(like in landline numbers or fax numbers)

**research**

I tried this with excel, but the process it would take an unreasonable amount of time(like 2 hours!)

**specs**

I have 400 contacts.
Windows XP SP 3

**please** help me solve this problem.

Comment: could you explain (a) ?

Comment: the question is , if the contact does not contatin a +, you have to add it. Am i ryt? or should you check if it contains `91` or not?

Comment: none of the contacts will contain a '+'

Comment: thanks all. but i got my answer. see @opensourcegeek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below??

```
import csv 
for row in csv.reader(['num1, 123456789', 'num2, 987654321', 'num3, +23456789']):
    phoneNumber = row[1].strip()
    if not phoneNumber.startswith('+'):
        phoneNumber = '+' + phoneNumber
    print phoneNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

Could use iterators to test each phone number as below:

```
phone_numbers = ['12234', '91232324', '913746', '3453' '9145653', '95843']

for i, number in enumerate(phone_numbers):
    phone_numbers[i] = ''.join(['+', phone_numbers[i]]) if number.startswith('91') else phone_numbers[i]
```

Hope that helps